# Developer PowerShell for Visual Studio 2022 is corrupted

Tags: powershell

Get these two messages when trying to open Developer PowerShell for Visual Studio 2022:

Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

I'm totally new to programming, so please explain in an easy step-by-step way how to fix this error in Visual Studio.

Have tried to reinstall Visual Studio, but didn't work.

Edit: just discovered that I can open the powershell from within VS but not when using search in Windows 10 to get the list which shows the app. The app icon for the powershell is not there, and get the above-mentioned error messages when trying to run the app as administrator

Answer (score 0):

if you use the explorer to go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
is powershell within this folder?

If you can find out where powershell.exe is located we'll be a step closer to figure out what the problem is. Maybe the shortcut sends you to the wrong place?

Maybe this could also help?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).